# Formatting Error when printing vertical histogram in java

Tags: java, histogram

This code

```
/**
 * <p>Title: Histogram</p>
 *
 * <p>Description: Histogram Drawing Class</p>
 *
 * <p>Copyright: Copyright (c) 2009</p>
 *
 * <p>Company: UMB</p>
 *
 * @author Bob Wilson
 * @version 03/04/2011
 */

public class Histogram 
{
  private int [] values;
  private int minIndex;
  private int maxIndex;
  private int maxLength;

  /** constructor for histogram drawing class
    * @param values: the array of integer values to draw
    * @param minIndex: the lowest index in the array for the range to draw
    * @param maxIndex: the highest index in the array for the range to draw
    * @param maxLength: the length of line to draw for the largest value
    */

  public Histogram(int [] values, int minIndex, int maxIndex, int maxLength) 
  {
    // initialize the values of the instance variables from the constructor parameters
    this.values = new int [maxIndex + 1];   // allocate memory for a copy of the values array
    this.minIndex = minIndex;
    this.maxIndex = maxIndex;
    this.maxLength = maxLength;

    // step 6: 
    // find largest number in values array for scaling length of bars

    int maxValue = values[0];  
    for ( int a = 1; a < values.length; a++){  
      if (values[a] > maxValue){  
        maxValue = values[a];  
      }  
    } 
    for ( int b = 1; b < values.length; b++) {
      values [b] = (values  [b] * maxLength) / maxValue;
    }

    // step 7:
    // copy data from values array to this.values array while scaling to maximum length of bars

    System.arraycopy(values,0,this.values,0,values.length);  


  }

  /** draw a horizontal bar graph
    */

  public void drawHor()
  {
      System.out.println("");

    // step 8:
    // draw horizontal bar graph (one line per roll value)

    for(int n = minIndex; n <= maxIndex; n++) {
      if (n < 10){
          System.out.print("Value " + n + ":  ");
      }
      else { 
          System.out.print("Value " + n + ": ");
      }

      for(int c = 1; c <= this.values[n]; c++) 
      {
        System.out.print("*"); 
      }
      System.out.println(" " + this.values[n]);       
    }
  }

  /** draw a vertical bar graph
    */

    public void drawVer()
    {
         System.out.println("");


    // step 9:
    // draw vertical bar graph (one column per roll value)
    for(int n = maxLength; n >= 1; n--)
    {

      if (n < 10){
          System.out.print("Count  " + n); 
      }
      else {
          System.out.print("Count " + n); 
      }

      for(int q = minIndex; q <= maxIndex; q++)
      {
        if (this.values[q] >= n)
        {
          System.out.print(" * ");
        }
        else
          System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
      System.out.println("Value:   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12");
    }
}

/*201040*/
```

prints formatting error in the vertical histogram where the spacing is completely wrong. It prints this

```
How many dice rolls do you want?
10
Estimated probablities:
Win:20.0%
Lose:10.0%
Roll again:70.0%

Value 2:  ************ 12
Value 3:   0
Value 4:   0
Value 5:  ************************************ 36
Value 6:  ************ 12
Value 7:  ************************ 24
Value 8:  ************ 12
Value 9:  ************************ 24
Value 10:  0
Value 11:  0
Value 12:  0

Count 36    *        
Count 35    *        
Count 34    *        
Count 33    *        
Count 32    *        
Count 31    *        
Count 30    *        
Count 29    *        
Count 28    *        
Count 27    *        
Count 26    *        
Count 25    *        
Count 24    *   *   *    
Count 23    *   *   *    
Count 22    *   *   *    
Count 21    *   *   *    
Count 20    *   *   *    
Count 19    *   *   *    
Count 18    *   *   *    
Count 17    *   *   *    
Count 16    *   *   *    
Count 15    *   *   *    
Count 14    *   *   *    
Count 13    *   *   *    
Count 12 *    *  *  *  *  *    
Count 11 *    *  *  *  *  *    
Count 10 *    *  *  *  *  *    
Count  9 *    *  *  *  *  *    
Count  8 *    *  *  *  *  *    
Count  7 *    *  *  *  *  *    
Count  6 *    *  *  *  *  *    
Count  5 *    *  *  *  *  *    
Count  4 *    *  *  *  *  *    
Count  3 *    *  *  *  *  *    
Count  2 *    *  *  *  *  *    
Count  1 *    *  *  *  *  *    
Value:   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

When it should be printing something much neater like this

```
How many dice rolls do you want?
 [1000]
Estimated probabilities for outcome of the first roll:
Win:          0.214
Lose:         0.119
Roll again:   0.667

Value 2:  ******* 7
Value 3:  ********** 10
Value 4:  ************* 13
Value 5:  ************************** 26
Value 6:  ****************************** 30
Value 7:  ************************************ 36
Value 8:  *************************** 27
Value 9:  *********************** 23
Value 10: ******************* 19
Value 11: ********* 9
Value 12: ****** 6

Count 36                *
Count 35                *
Count 34                *
Count 33                *
Count 32                *
Count 31                *
Count 30             *  *
Count 29             *  *
Count 28             *  *
Count 27             *  *  *
Count 26          *  *  *  *
Count 25          *  *  *  *
Count 24          *  *  *  *
Count 23          *  *  *  *  *
Count 22          *  *  *  *  *
Count 21          *  *  *  *  *
Count 20          *  *  *  *  *
Count 19          *  *  *  *  *  *
Count 18          *  *  *  *  *  *
Count 17          *  *  *  *  *  *
Count 16          *  *  *  *  *  *
Count 15          *  *  *  *  *  *
Count 14          *  *  *  *  *  *
Count 13       *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Count 12       *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Count 11       *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Count 10    *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Count  9    *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Count  8    *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Count  7 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Count  6 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Count  5 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Count  4 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Count  3 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Count  2 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Count  1 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
Value:   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
```

I can't figure out why this is happening or how to fix it. Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your spacing in the `drawVert()` method is off. Some is just simple yet easily fixed, but there is some sloppy coding on your part. While decreasing the time complexity is good, there must be correct code. By spacing your numbers out, you can allow for a prettier x-axis, and by revisiting your stars, you'd see that you didn't have equivalent spacing when there was a hit versus when there was no hit. Try looking at the output and at your `drawVert()` method

A modified code snippet:

```
    if (this.values[q] >= n)
    {
      System.out.print(" * "); //leading whitespace, asterisk, trailing whitespace = 3
    }
    else {
      System.out.print("   "); //whitespace, whitespace, whitespace = 3
    }
  System.out.println();

  System.out.print("Values: ");
  for(int i = minIndex; i < maxIndex; i++) {
    if(i < 10) {
      System.out.print(" " + i + " ");//leading and trailing whitespace for single digit vals
    } else {
      System.out.print(" " + i);//only leading for double digit vals
    }
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```